# Show product-category thumbnails in loop which have n price of products in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I want to show category thumbnails in loop which has n price of products.
Here n price will put from admin panel where a amount will fill and that products-category thumbnail will appear on a page which having that amount or greater than that amount of products.
so please help me to write a query or any other solution if you can give me.

Comment: Abdul, Post the code you have tried.

Comment: I just do some cheat with code but If you have better suggestion that would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code and get succeed.

```
//backend option for price
$value=  get_option('price');
// the query            
    $args = array ('meta_query' => array(
                                        array(  'key'       => '_price',
                                                'value'     => $value,
                                                'compare'   => '>=',
                                                'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                                             ),
                                        ),
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                  );

// The Query
            $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

            <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <!-- the loop -->
            <?php $stack = array();?>
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $a = $product->get_categories(); ?>
         <?php if (!in_array($a, $stack)) : ?> 
            <li class="product-category">
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
                foreach ( $terms as $term ){
                  $category_name = $term->name;
                  $category_id = $term->term_id;
                  $category_slug = $term->slug;
$category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
         $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
     echo '<img class="absolute category-image" src="'.$image.'">';
                }
        echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $category_slug, 'product_cat' ) . '?min_price='.$value.'&max_price=1000500' . '">' . $category_name . '</a>';

?>
```